# Floating Basic jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

I´m using the Basic jQuery slider (http://www.basic-slider.com) on my website: http://www.bizgamesstudios.com/

My goal is to float the slider to the left so that the bullet points beneath would stand side by side with the slider. However, when applying float: left the slider collapses.

Any ideas on how to do this without changing the appearance of the slider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply these properties to .featureList:

```
float: right;
margin-top: -300px;
margin-right: -80px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your slideshow had a max-width set but not an actual width set.
Once it floated left, your #content did not account for your slideshow's height.

Adding the height of the #content, width of the #slideshow, and #width to your feature list, should work.

Try this CSS:

```
#slideshow {
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    }

.featureList {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    }

#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    background: #fff;
    height: 600px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your site is fixed width, you could add a width to the  and float it right:

```
.featureList {
    width: 530px;
    float: right;
}
```

Also, change the max-width on #slideshow to a width:

```
#slideshow {
  width: 600px;
}
```

Lastly, you'll want to add the clearfix class to the #game1 div